# Expression for the mass of a wedge of a solid uniform hemisphere

Tags: geometry, functions

When trying to calculate the centre of mass of a solid hemisphere, I split my hemisphere into small wedges as seen in the following picture:

[image: Hemisphere with wedge]

Apparently the mass of the wedge, $dm$, equals
$$dm = 3M/(2\pi R^3) \times \pi r^2dy.$$ Could someone please explain me how you can find this equation for $dm$? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The element of mass in the infinitesimal slice is $dm=\rho dV$ where $\rho$ is the
density and $dV$ is the (infinitesimal) volume of the slice. The volume of the slice (think of it as an infinitesimal cylinder of radius $r$ and height $dy$) is $dV=\pi r^2dy$. The density of the piece is its total mass $M$ divided by its total volume  $V_t=2\pi R^3/3$, so $\rho=3M/2\pi R^3$. This gives your expression for the mass of the slice.